# How to plot an OOB error vs the number of trees in random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I fitted a random forest model. I have used both `randomForest` and `ranger` package. I didn't tune number of trees in a forest, I just left it with default number, which is 500. Now I would like to see if it is enough, i.e. if error have reached a plateau or not. So I believe I would need to extract the individual trees, take at random for example 100, 200, 300, 400 and finally 500 trees, take oob trees out of them and calculate the OOB error for 100, 200, ... trees consecutively. Then I could plot OOB error vs the number of trees. I found that `randomForest::getTree` and `ranger::treeInfo` returns a data.frame of trees, but I can't figure out what is what there. What's more `ranger::treeInfo` returns a data frame with 50% NAs and the overall output is even harder to read.
So my question are:

1. How can I plot the OOB error vs number of trees used in a forest if I already have a random forest with 500 trees?
2. Why `ranger::treeInfo` have 50% NAs and actually only those rows have predictions?

Here's minimal example:

```
mpg2 <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(is_suv = as.factor(class == 'suv')) %>% 
  select(-class)
mpg_model <- ranger::ranger(is_suv ~ ., data = mpg2)
ranger::treeInfo(mpg_model, tree = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is just `plot(.)` , as in this example :

```
library(randomForest)

set.seed(71)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance = TRUE, proximity=TRUE)
# plot the model
plot(iris.rf)
# add legend to know which is which
legend("top", colnames(iris.rf$err.rate), fill=1:ncol(iris.rf$err.rate))
```

As for the `randomForest::getTree` and `ranger::treeInfo`, those have nothing to do with the OOB and they simply describe an outline of the -chosen- tree, i.e., which nodes are on which criteria splitted and to which nodes is connected, each package uses a slightly different representation, the following for example comes from `ranger::treeInfo`:

```
     nodeID leftChild rightChild splitvarID splitvarName splitval terminal prediction
1       0         1          2          4  Petal.Width     0.80    FALSE       <NA>
2       1        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE     setosa
```

which is basically a description of something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What different colours means? And how it can be done with `ranger` package?

Comment: the legend will indicate what does each color represent, and you can plot the `OOB` only with the call `plot(x = 1:nrow(iris.rf$err.rate), y = iris.rf$err.rate[,1], type='l')`, it might be easier to understand if you take a look at `iris.rf$err.rate` (the error rates of the model), as for `ranger`, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with a way to extract the OOB for each tree.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same iris example as above, I think something like this would work.

```
lev <- c("OOB", levels(iris.rf$y))
err <- c()
for (i in 1:length(lev)) {
  err <- c(err, iris.rf$err.rate[,lev[i]])
}

oob.error.data <- data.frame(
  Trees = rep(1:nrow(iris.rf$err.rate), times = 1 + (length(levels(iris.rf$y)))),
  Type = rep(biolev, each = nrow(iris.rf$err.rate)),
  Error = err)

ggplot(data = oob.error.data, aes(x = Trees, y = Error)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Type))
```

Check out [Josh Starmer's example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EXPYzbfLCE) of randomForest in R on youtube for details `

`